# Image replacement and compositing: Not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, python, image, animation, composite

First off here is the [example](http://makeagif.com/i/IaGxAm):

How do I programmatically replace the red boxes with pictures and keep the animation? Then export a new image seq with the changes.  Can this be done?

I mostly work in javascript or python, but I am open to other languages.

I am looking into Pillow for python and caman.js for javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please remember to follow ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide when asking a question.

Comment: I have thought about using blender or adobe after effects to do the work for me, but I want to be able to do this from a web site.  Say people upload there photos and that is what is replacing the red boxes. I will have lots of instances of AE or blender opened at the some time. Which might slow the servers way down.  I am new to programming so I am not completely sure where to go.

Comment: If you are new to programming I'd suggest starting from something much easier. Consider gaining more knowledge at for example [Code Academy](http://codeacademy.com). Working with image manipulation is hard stuff, without your personal research effort I don't think anybody will help.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for as far as research. I am reading the Pillow docs and caman.js docs now.  I have written a script in after effects to do all the replacing. With pillow I know how to  blend 2 images together and crop one and put it into another. I will use ffmpeg to make a video after the process. I have been search google for python/javascript image processing,image manipulation,image compositing. Nothing is really talking about how to track an item and replace it with another.  Most talk about how to create filters like instagram. What do you suggest for research?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to write some code and showing certain problem you can't solve. As I mentioned to get community response you'll need to show certain algorithmic problem. I'm not expert in this subject so personally I can't suggest anything further.